# element $(this) output different format in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I’m looping through elements with the same class name and printing the element using `console.log` as follows:

```
$('.thumbImg').each(function(i) {
  console.log("i is", i, "this is", this);
});
```

However the `console.log`’s output is unexpected, changing at random between the following formats:

```html
i is 13 this is img.thumbImg
i is 14 this is <img class=​"thumbImg" src=​"images/​bookcovers/​jekyllhyde.jpg" alt>​
```

The preferred format is the second full element output.

Here is a screenshot of my console:

[image]

I think this is causing problems with loading these images later in my program, could anyone point me in the right direction to a fix?

Comment: What happens if you click on the little arrows before each `img.thumbImg`?

Comment: Why dont you check `typeof` and `console.dir()` to help you debug.

Comment: @Xufox the drop arrow give a verbose list that i've uploaded here: http://pastebin.com/Rhbu4vSG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
$('.thumbImg').each(function(key,element) {
alert("i is "+ key+ " this is "+ element.outerHTML);
});
```

An example here:  [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqehs0o2/)

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to print out in the console?

Try something like this:

```
$('.thumbImg').each(function(i) {
    console.log("i is", i, "this is", $(this));
});
```

Or maybe a attr?

```
$('.thumbImg').each(function(i) {
    console.log("i is", i, "this is", $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Make sure you have this wrapped around it so the site can load first then loop through your images.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    /* code here */ 
});
```

Comment: It says “The preferred format is the second full element output” right in the question.

Comment: Not sure if I follow. I was asking you what you are trying to print out... not what the error message is.

Comment: Did you try anything I gave you? Or just automatically assumed it wouldn't work. Try the document on ready function.

Comment: The first two are not the expected output: the OP said that the preferred format (i.e. the _desired output_) is the _full element output_; it’s not just the URL and it’s not a jQuery object. And the third suggestion is useless, because the DOM is loaded at the time of execution, otherwise the jQuery object would contain 0 objects instead of 20. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: This is most certainly jQuery. I use jQuery on a day-to-day basis. Still not sure what is being asked.

Comment: By “and it’s not a jQuery object” I mean “and _the desired output_ (‘it’) is not a jQuery object”, as in “the jQuery object is not the desired output”.

Comment: I wish more information was provided so it's easier to troubleshoot. I think that's the main problem. Because looping an array of objects shouldn't be hard.